# Computing tree alignment distance

Tags: algorithms, trees, dynamic-programming

I am implementing the dynamic programming algorithm for computing tree alignment distance as described in "[Alignment of trees — an alternative to tree edit](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397595800299)". But I got stuck in lemma 3 on page 141 (page 5 of pdf). The notations are given at the beginning of section 2. The last case in lemma 3 says

[image: formula]

However, there is no recurrence formula given to compute [image]. How did we obtain this?

I don't think the following holds either:
[image: x]?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  I think you should be asking a more basic question: what is the definition of $F_1[i_s]$?  Anyway, a good way to approach this is probably to try to prove the lemma yourself.  Do you understand the proofs of the other cases (Case 1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3)?  I suggest studying those, then trying to apply a similar methodology to reason about that case (Case 3) and try to derive a formula on your own.  Also, I don't know what your final line is referring to ("I don't think..."), but in any case, we prefer that you ask only one question per post.

Comment: $F_1[i_s]$ is actually defined in section 2 as the first forest under node $i_s$. My concern was that the recurrence relationship are of forests starting from $i_1, j_1$ but we need $D(F_1[i_s], F_2[j_k, j_t])$ which start with $j_k$ and not $j_1$. 

Anyhow, thanks for your help :)

Comment: OK, got it -- I overlooked that.  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Could you give some more context, please? People shouldn't have to go find section2 of a document that you've liked just to figure out what you're even talking about. Also, please replace the images of equations with LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the paper correctly (and I might not), the solution seems to be described in Section 2.2 of the paper.  It says "we have to compute $D(F_1[i],F_2[j_s,j_t])$..." and then it goes on to describe a strategy for doing so (namely, the Procedure 1, as described in Figure 2).